# Change Windows service with PowerShell script

Tags: windows, powershell, service

I wrote a PowerShell script to change the login user for a service on my remote VMs. It works when I execute it. However, when I send it to my coworkers, the script appears that it ran without errors and they checked it still listed as "local account'.

```
$account  = Read-Host "Please admin account Name"
$password = Read-Host -AsSecureString "Please enter your password"
$password = [System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::PtrToStringAuto([System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal]::SecureStringToBSTR($password))
$service  = Read-Host "Enter service name"

$computers = Get-Content -Path ".\servers.txt"

foreach ($computer in $computers) {
  $svc = gwmi Win32_Service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "name='$service'"
  $svc.StopService()
  $svc.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
  $svc.StartService()
}

Write-Host $service "is now running as" $account
Read-Host
```

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what the errors are.  A good starting point, are you sure they have a text file called servers.txt in the same directory as your code?  Does their PowerShell Execution Policy allow for remote code to run?  Also, you're having them type in their password.  You should use `Get-Credential` instead, it would be MUCH safer.

Comment: I'd output the `$computer` because it sounds very much that your script didn't find `.\servers.txt` and decided it had nothing to do.

Comment: for the server.txt is reading the name of the VM from a servers.txt file that they update. There arent any error messages being provided it just looks like it ran with out issues but no changes are made on on their specified vm.

Comment: @FoxDeploy In general yes, but since [`Change()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384901.aspx) requires a plaintext password anyway using `Get-Credential` won't improve anything.

Comment: Coding aside, does the account on the remote PCs have "logon as a service" rights?

Comment: @simon Catlin, im not sure I can look into that.

Answer (score 0):

I would move this block

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
$svc = gwmi Win32_Service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "name='$service'"
$svc.StopService()     
$svc.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
$svc.StartService()
}
```

into a `invoke-command` block. Cmd-lets using the `-Computer` parameter implement the remote actions in a proprietary way, while `invoke-command` uses `WSMAN` (-> more standardized way).

Try this:

```
foreach ($computer in $computers) {
   # $computer can be either an IP-address or a FQDN e.g. computer.mydomain
   invoke-command -computer $computer -credential (get-credential) -scripblock {
      $svc = gwmi Win32_Service -ComputerName $computer -Filter "name='$service'"
      $svc.StopService()     
      $svc.Change($null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$null,$account,$password,$null,$null,$null)
      $svc.StartService()
   }
}
```

With that proposal all actions are performed on the remote machine. In contrary to the first attempt. The first attempt "fetches" the remote objects to you local machine (objects are converted), than you locally perform some actions on the converted object (-> changed properties are send back to the remote).

If your computer is not in the same domain as the remote ones, you've to add your remote targets to your local trusted host list. This [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx) describes how to update your trusted hosts list.

You should also check if Powershell remoting is active on your targets, also described in this [link](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff700227.aspx). If your target OS is WIN Server 2012 R2 Powershell remoting is active per default.

Comment: thanks for trying but I got the following error when i tried to run it: "invoke-command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri
parameter, or pass URI objects instead of strings."

Comment: Check if you need to add the remote targets in your trusted hosts list. I've updated my answer.